# Projective equivalence: Linear subspaces under the action of $PGL_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebraic-geometry

A pair of ordered collections linear subspaces $\Lambda_1, \ldots, \Lambda_k$ and $\Lambda'_1, \ldots, \Lambda'_k$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ are called projectively equivalent if there exists a regular automorphism $\phi : \mathbb{P}^n \to \mathbb{P}^n$ (equivalently, a member of $PGL_{n+1}$) such that $\phi(\Lambda_i) = \Lambda'_i$ for each $i$.

It is well-known that two ordered sets of $n+2$ points in $\mathbb{P}^n$ in general position are projectively equivalent, and that any two ordered sets of three pairwise disjoint lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$ are projectively equivalent. Likewise, any two pairs of a hyperplane in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and a point outside of it are projectively equivalent.

Three pairwise disjoint lines satisfies the condition that no two of them lies in a 2-plane, which is a condition on their relative position similar to points in general position.

I have two questions:

1) In what sense does collections of linear subspaces lie in general position? Is it simply that any subset of them span a linear subspace of maximal dimension?

2) What kind of "classifying theorems" are there regarding which pairs of collections of ordered linear subspaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$ (in general position, or other types of conditions) are projectively equivalent? I'm looking for a sharp relation between the number $k$, the individual dimensions of each $\Lambda_i$, and the strictness of the condition of their relative position under which two such collections are projectively equivalent.

Perhaps such a theorem is best formulated in terms of Grassmannians.

Answer (score 1):

1) As far as the $PGL(n+1)$ action is concerned, the general position is given exactly by what you describe: the spans having maximal dimension.

2) If you want the action to be transitive on a tuple of subspaces of dimension $(d_1, \dots, d_k)$, that's the same as saying a fixed choice of subspaces $\Lambda_i^* \in Gr(d_i+1, n+1)$ can be mapped to an arbitrary tuple $(\Lambda_1, \dots, \Lambda_k)$.
By a simple dimension count, this should happen when $\sum \dim Gr(d_i + 1, n+1) \le \dim PGL(n+1)$, or $\sum (d_i+1)(n-d_i) \le n(n+2)$. So for points, each $d_i = 0$, and hence the action is transitive as long as $kn \le n(n+2)$ or $k \le n+2$.